# Getting data with dynamic routing

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a catalog item, by clicking I generate a slug and insert it into the NuxtLink.

Now in the component I need to get a specific element from the array, but I don't have a slug in the array. With the help of id, I would be able to find the desired element. I don't provide any id to Nuxt routing.

If I can somehow get the id of the desired element, then how do I do it?

I think it would be a bad idea to record the id in the pinia store.

How do they act in such situations in general? I use nuxt 3.

```js
<NuxtLink class="catalog-item" :to="`catalog/${slug}`"></NuxtLink>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the params property to pass the id of the desired element as a route parameter.

```
<NuxtLink class="catalog-item" :to="`catalog/${slug}/${id}`"></NuxtLink>
```

Then, in the component that is rendered when the NuxtLink is clicked, you can access the id route parameter using the $route.params.id property.

```
mounted() {
  const id = this.$route.params.id
  // use the id to get the desired element from the array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer decoupling the router param through props in the Component. Official [docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html)

```
props: {
        id: {
            type: Number,
            required: true,
        },
    },
```

Then in router file you need to enable props:

```
const routes = [{ path: '/user/:id', component: User, props: true }]
```